# How can I shorten a function which outputs the chain numbers of the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: python, recursion, collatz, aesthetics

This Python function outputs a list based on the collatz conjecture. This is an unsolved maths problem where the function will perform different operations on 'n' depending on if it is odd or even, outputting 'n' to a list called 'seq' each time the function repeats. Eventually 'n' will decay to the end point ('1') once the number '16' appears in the 'chain'.

I am trying to make the code as concise as possible here. Is there any way to shorten the function?

This is my newbie Python code:

```
def collatz(n):

    seq = []
    n = int(n)

    if n == 0:
        return 
    
    elif n == 1:
        return seq + [n]
    
    elif n > 1 == True and n % 2 == 0:
        return seq + [n] + collatz(n/2)
    
    else:
        return seq + [n] + collatz(3*n+1)

print(collatz(7))
```

this outputs

```
[7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove `seq = []` and all other references to `seq`. That variable does nothing in your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now, the function you gave isn't fully robust for negative inputs and 0: I would rewrite it as such below. I think yours is very readable though, and I wouldn't promote more conciseness: readability > conciseness almost always.

```
def collatz(n):

    seq = []
    n = int(n)

    if n <= 0:
        return False
    
    elif n == 1:
        return seq + [n]
    
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return seq + [n] + collatz(n/2)
    
    else:
        return seq + [n] + collatz(3*n+1)

print(collatz(7))
```

If you really want more concise code, consider this solution by @Kelly Bundy:

```
def collatz(n):
    return [1] if n == 1 else [n] + collatz(3*n+1 if n%2 else n//2)

print(collatz(7))
```

Alternatively, an iterative rather than recursive solution

```
def collatz(n):
    seq = [n]
    while n != 1:
        n = 3*n+1 if n%2 else n//2
        seq.append(n)
    return seq
```

Sanitise your inputs as you wish.

Comment: Except that the if should be: `if n <= 0:`, otherwise the returned list doesn't contain a final `1`.

Comment: Why the hyper-complicated recursive call?

Comment: Especially since you talk about readability :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy That's a rather good point - The original used recursion and I decided to follow suite, but of course iterative solutions are much more robust for large inputs, and faster too. I have added an iterative solution too :)

Comment: Actually I didn't mean the recursion but the expression you use to compute the next n value there. I mean, I'd write it as `def collatz(n): return [1] if n == 1 else [n] + collatz(3*n+1 if n%2 else n//2)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Had no idea you could write python if statements like that inside the function call. I guess you learn something new everyday.

Comment: It's not an If statement. You indeed can't write statements inside expressions. Only expressions. And that's a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

I've got issues with the *more readable* version of the currently selected answer.  First, there's no need for the `else` and `elif` statements given the `return` statements.

Second, I wouldn't endorse a function that returns a boolean sometimes and a list otherwise.  The return type should be consistent:

```
def collatz(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return []

    if n == 1:
        return [n]

    if n % 2:
        return [n, *collatz(3 * n + 1)]

    return [n, *collatz(n // 2)]

print(collatz(7))
```